# Volume of the solid bounded by the elliptic cylinder $9x^2+4y^2 = 36$ and the plane $3x+4y-6z=0$ in the first octant

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to compute the volume enclosed by the elliptic cylinder $9x^2+4y^2 = 36$ and the plane $3x+4y-6z=0$ in the first octant. This solid can be described as
$$ \mathcal{R} = \left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 9x^2+4y^2 \leq 36, \, x, y \geq 0, \, 0 \leq z \leq \frac{3x+4y}{6}\right\},$$
so its volume is
$$ \text{vol}(\mathcal{R}) = \iint_{\substack{9x^2+4y^2\leq 36 \\ x, y \geq 0}} \frac{3x+4y}{6}\, dx dy = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{36-9x^2}}{2}} \frac{3x+4y}{6} \, dy dx.$$
But this integral equals $6,$ while the solution is supposed to be $10.$ Have I made a mistake somewhere or is the solution wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I get 6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The region of integration is

$ D = \{(x, y) | x \ge 0, y \ge 0 , 9x^2 + 4y^2 \le 36 \} $

The $z$ value at $(x, y)$ is $z= \dfrac{1}{6}(3 x + 4 y) $

The best way to handle this problem is to introduce a change of variables.

Let $ x = 2 r \cos(t) $, and $ y = 3 r \sin(t) $, then the Jacobian is

$ | J | = \bigg| \dfrac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial (t, r) } \bigg| = \bigg| \begin{vmatrix} - 2 r \sin(t) && 2 \cos(t) \\ 3 r \cos(t) && 3 \sin(t) \end{vmatrix} \bigg| = 6 r $

So now the integral becomes

$ V = \displaystyle \int_{r=0}^1 \int_{t=0}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{1}{6} (6 r \cos(t) + 12 r \sin(t) ) (6 r) dt  dr  \\
= \displaystyle \int_{r = 0}^1 18 r^2 dr = 6 $

So the volume is $\boxed{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the limits and order of integration disagree in your last expression. You need to evaluate either
$$ \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{36-9x^2}}{2}} \frac{3x+4y}{6} dydx$$
or
$$ \int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{36-4y^2}}{3}} \frac{3x+4y}{6} dxdy .$$

Comment: You're right, but that was a typo. It is your first integral that I had computed and yields 6 instead of 10.

Comment: Interesting. I also get 6 when I evaluate. All your other work looks good to me. There's always a chance that answer keys are wrong.